# Pregunta sobre Ficheros

Tags: java

Tengo este pequeño programa Java que escribe datos en un fichero. El programa funciona pero hay cosas que no entiendo o no veo claras.

```
package escrituraFicheroBinarios;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class WriteBinario2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        DataOutputStream salida = null;
        int n;

        try {
            //leemos datos de entrada por teclado y los escribimos en un fichero del objeto fos
            fos = new FileOutputStream("/ficheros/datos2.txt");
            salida = new DataOutputStream(fos);

            System.out.print("Introduce caracteres. INTRO para acabar: ");

            do {
                n = (char) System.in.read();
                if (n !='\n'){
                    salida.writeChar(n); //se escribe el número entero en el fichero
                }
            } while (n != '\n');
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                if (fos != null) {
                    fos.close();
                }
                if (salida != null) {
                    salida.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

DUDAS

```
n = (char) System.in.read();
```

1) El método read() transforma el primer byte de datos que haya introducido por teclado el usuario en un número entero entre 0-255. ¿Es correcto?

2) El anterior entero se pasa a char. ¿Por qué se hace este casteo? ¿Es una forma de traducir el anterior entero a formato ASCII?

```
salida.writeChar(n);
```

3) ¿El método writeChar(n) qué interpreta el entero anterior como ASCII y lo escribe en el fichero? ¿Por qué a esta función se le pasa un tipo entero en lugar de un char tal como da a pensar el nombre de la misma?

4) ¿Por qué si escribo por teclado la letra «ñ», me la traduce a ASCII (241) pero NO me lo escribe en el fichero?

5) Si se supone que estoy trabajando con datos binarios ¿Cómo es posible que pueda visualizar lo que se escribe en el fichero? ¿No tendría que estar insertando datos binarios solo legibles por el ordenador?

No consigo entender en profundidad el tema y estoy un poco atascado con la tontería.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: No es recomendable poner tantas preguntas en la descripción, debido a que, harás que el lector deba investigar más y posiblemente se aburrirá y no te responderán nada. Lo que recomiendo es que formules diversas preguntas en la cual tenga una duda especifica.

Answer (score 1):

> > 1.) El método read() transforma el primer byte de datos que haya introducido por teclado el usuario en un número entero entre 0-255. ¿Es correcto?

Respuesta: **No.** Porque internamente ya está como número entero (obviamente en bits). Cuando se ejecute esta línea de código:

```java
n = (char) System.in.read();
```

El programa se pausará hasta que el usuario ingrese un dato. Así que vamos asumir que el usuario introdujo por teclado lo siguiente:

```java
AAA
```

Esos caracteres estarán en el búfer del teclado (donde se almacenan los caracteres al momento de presionar una tecla) de esta manera:

```
65  65  65  \n
```

Hay que tomar en cuenta que en memoria lo que se guarde no es el caracter, sino, su respectivo código ASCII que corresponde a un número entero. El salto de línea también se almacena en el búfer, debido a que, al momento de presionar la tecla `enter`, genera un `\n`.

El método [read()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read()) lee un dato a la vez, esto quiere decir, que en nuestro ejemplo lo primero que va a leer será el número `65` (que corresponde al caracter `A`) y básicamente eso es lo que retorna el método.

**¿Por qué el método read() retorna un integer y no un char?**

Según la documentación del método [read()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read()), retorna valores de `0` a `255`, pero si encuentra el final del archivo (es decir, cuando no se encuentre más caracteres en el archivo) en el búfer, devolverá `-1`. Entonces aquí podemos deducir que el método `read()` no puede tener como tipo de valor de retorno un `char`, debido a que, el tipo `char` en Java solo admite valores de `0` a `65535` (ver [Primitive Data Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)). En cambio, una variable `int` si admite valores negativos.

> > 2.1 El anterior entero se pasa a char. ¿Por qué se hace este casteo?

El "casteo" es innecesario. El "casting" simplemente le dice al compilador que el valor que retornará el método `read()` será de `0` a `255`, aunque en realidad es una falacia, porque este método también puede devolver `-1`, por lo tanto, ese casting no se debería hacer, debido a que, su tipo de valor de retorno es `Integer`.

También recalco que el entero no se pasa a `char`, debido a que, tanto una variable `int` y `char` almacenan números enteros.

> > 2.2 ¿Es una forma de traducir el anterior entero a formato ASCII?

**No.** El entero ya está en formato ASCII. Al momento que el método `read()` retorne el número entero será el código ASCII y ese valor, se lo almacena una variable de tipo `int`.

> > 5.1 ¿Cómo es posible que pueda visualizar lo que se escribe en el fichero?

En realidad si es posible.

**Ejemplo:** Si en el fichero binario se escribe el número `65`, en memoria tuviese lo siguiente:

```java
//El 65 en binario es:
1000001
```

Esto quiere decir, que al momento de abrir el fichero binario con algún editor de texto como Bloc de notas, aparecerá en pantalla el caracter `65` y esto se debe, porque el editor asume que el contenido del fichero son códigos ASCII, sin embargo, en este caso, el archivo tenía un código ASCII.

Pero esto no siempre es así. Miremos el siguiente ejemplo:

```java
salida.writeInt(255);
```

El número `255` se escribirá en un registro de 4 bytes. Entonces al momento de abrir el fichero, no se mostrará el `255`, sino, caracteres extraños.

**¿Por qué paso esto?**

Como en el registro se almacenó un `255`, el editor de texto asume que es código ASCII y lo traduce como sea, haciendo que se muestre caracteres raros.

Otro ejemplo sería esto:

```java
salida.writeChars("David");
```

La cadena `David` estará en un objeto de tipo `String`, pero a la hora de escribirlo en el archivo, se consumirá 5 registros donde estará el caracter almacenado (obviamente en binario). Entonces al momento de abrir el archivo binario con un editor de texto, nos mostrará el nombre `David` debido a que, internamente, cada registro, almacena un código ASCII, por lo tanto, la traducción (transforma los códigos de cada caracter en **CARACTER**) del editor se hace de forma exitosa.

> > 5.2 ¿No tendría que estar insertando datos binarios solo legibles por el ordenador?

Por más que sea un archivo binario o de texto, estarás insertando internamente, números binarios. La diferencia radica en el contenido del archivo.

**Por ejemplo:**

Si almacenas el número `23.4` en un fichero de texto, en realidad se lo convierte en una secuencia de caracteres, dando como resultado 4 registros de memoria.

En cambio, si lo guardas en un fichero binario, se almacena el número `23.4` directamente en un registro, sin la necesidad de una conversión.

Answer (score -1):

Java no se basa en ASCII, sino que utiliza UNICODE, mira la [ñ](https://elcodigoascii.com.ar/codigos-ascii-extendidos/letra-n-tilde-enie-minuscula-codigo-ascii-164.html) en ASCII es 164...
y en java las ñ es:241

```
System.out.println((int)'ñ');// result 241
```

no es recomendable que hagas eso:`n = (char) System.in.read();`

Es mejor si usas la clases **Scanner** y **PrintStream**

```
PrintStream salida = new PrintStream(fos);
Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

while(entrada.hasNextLine())
{
    salida.println(sc.nextLine());
}

salida.close();
entrada.close();
```

para terminar de responder tu pregunta, te diré que los caracteres son compatibles con los enteros, así que si tienes el caracter(char) y lo quieres escribir, solo haz lo siguiente:

```
char varchar = extrada.next().charAt(0);//input: ñ\t
salida.writeChar((int)varchar);
```

Comment: Estoy revisando lo que me has puesto. Me dices que java no se basa en ASCII. Por las pruebas que estoy haciendo, cuando introduzco un char dentro de una variable int, me la almacena con su código en formato decimal. Por ejemplo:         char caracter = 'a';
        
        System.out.println("Primero: "+caracter);
        
        int num;
        
        num = caracter;
        
        System.out.println("Segundo: "+num);

Comment: Tienes que decirle a sistema de forma explícita que la transforme a entero o a carácter.... char character = 'x';int num = (int) character; character = (char)num;